# FFMPEG Preview from Capture device

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am using MacOS with FFMPEG --enabled-decklink installed to capture from BlackMagic Ultrastudio Expressto SDI to Thunderbolt and streams it to youtube, it works perfectly fine, here is my code.

```
ffmpeg -f decklink -format_code 'Hi50'  -i 'UltraStudio Express'
-deinterlace -b:v 1M -vcodec h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -color_range 1  -acodec aac  -f  flv  rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/*******
```

but I am kinda blind cuz I cannot see what I am capturing till its live on Youtube, is there away to preview the video locally on my Mac before I start streaming via ffmpeg?

Comment: If RTMP doesn't block, you can split the video. See the wiki page for [Creating Multiple Outputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) and the [split filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit). Send the second output to your local computer. Also, this question is better for the Super User Stack Exchange network.

Comment: You don't want the split filter. In @Cornstalks' first link, see the tee pseudo-muxer section.

Comment: Thanks Cornstalks and Mulvya, but this process of creating multiple outputs will start the stream to Youtube as well, the main reason of what I am asking for is to see the video before start streaming. how about creating two process, lets say first process "Preview" streams udp://Localhost - Open VLC and view it, then open another FFMPEG process and initiate second stream "Stream". I will try it if it works not sure if decklink card will allow two capturing at the same time ? what about the processing ?

Comment: As I expected it didnt work, only one at the time works cannot capture twice at the same time